# Redis keys are saved two times ..checking from dbsize command

Tags: redis

I am saving no.of(1000) records in Redis DB , while checking in redis CLI dbsize as its exactly double actually. Can any one having any idea why its saved double? Thanks!

Comment: how to save your data in redis db? therefor you can use Redis Desktop Manager for check your data visually, if you need help, show your code

Comment: Not a lot is clear from our question, can you frame the question better or elaborate our question further?

Comment: Hi, please add the part of your code that is not working as expected in order to add some clarity to your request. Thanks.